# Java: refer to a class variable using a variable

Tags: java

File `Lists_of_values.java`:

```
public class Lists_of_values {
    public static List<String> circumstances = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Medical", "Maternity", "Bereavement", "Other"));
    public static List<String> interruptions = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Awaiting results", "Courses not available", "Fieldwork",
            "Health reasons", "Internship with stipend", "Other"));
}
```

File `Main_file.java`:

```
public String getDropdownValues(String lovs) {
    String templovList = StringUtils.join(Lists_of_values.lovs, ' ');
    return templovList;
}
```

This is giving me: `lovs cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Is there a way to use a variable in this context as a parameter in `getDropdownValues`? So that I can just call `getDropdownValues("circumstances")`.

Comment: just use `lovs` if you want to pass a parameter

Comment: have a look at reflection

Comment: BTW `Arrays.asList` is also a `List`

Comment: You could create `enum`s holding your strings, so that you are still typesafe. Or you could create a [`Supplier<List<String>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and pass it to `getDropdownValues()`.

Comment: A) follow Java naming conventions. You dont use _ in class names. B) constants should be all upper case C) When you have a constant list of strings, simply use `Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")` to create that list. And of course: that thing should be final. There are so many subtle low level problems that I am wondering if you are really at a point where you should start using reflection. Reflection is an advanced topic, and more importantly, you only use it when you have good reasons to. This rather sounds like you have a bad design, and now you want to fix it using reflection ...

Comment: @GhostCat Indeed, I'm 95% certain that the OP does not need or want reflection here.

Comment: @JimmyB I am 65% confident that the OP doesn't know what he should need or want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also introduce a Map that holds a reference based on the name:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lists_of_values {
    public static List<String> circumstances = Arrays.asList("Medical", "Maternity", "Bereavement", "Other");
    public static List<String> interruptions = Arrays.asList("Awaiting results", "Courses not available", "Fieldwork", "Health reasons", "Internship with stipend", "Other");

    private static Map<String, List<String>> lists = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        lists.put("circumstances", circumstances);
        lists.put("interruptions", interruptions);
    }

    public static List<String> getList(String name) {
        return lists.get(name);
    }
}
```

That would be used as: `List_of_Values.getList("circumstances")`

This would also allow your code to be obfuscated, which would break if you decide to use reflection.

Comment: Thanks, this works as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot (Unless you resort to reflection APIs)

A right way would be to pass the appropriate list to `getDropdownValues`

```
public String getDropdownValues(List<String> list) {
    String templovList = StringUtils.join(list, ' ');
    return templovList;
}
```

Call it as

```
getDropdownValues(circumstances); //or getDropdownValues(interruptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I call `getDropdownValues(Lists_of_values.circumstances)`, it is empty...

Comment: Should qualify `circumstances` with its class name: `Lists_of_values.circumstances`.

Comment: @JimmyB Maybe, or you can do a static import and also it is not needed when calling from `Lists_of_values` itself

Comment: @Alichino `circumstances` will get initialized when the class `Lists_of_values` is loaded and it cannot be empty unless it got removed or emptied